# c++ passing function as argument to another function with void pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments, void

I'm trying to pass a function as argument to another function with void pointer and it doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print()
{
    cout << "hello!" << endl;
}

void execute(void* f()) //receives the address of print
{
    void (*john)(); // declares pointer to function
    john = (void*) f; // assigns address of print to pointer, specifying print returns nothing
    john(); // execute pointer
}

int main()
{
    execute(&print); // function that sends the address of print
    return 0;
}
```

The thing are the void function pointers, I could make an easier code like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print();
void execute(void());

int main()
{
    execute(print); // sends address of print
    return 0;
}

void print()
{
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}

void execute(void f()) // receive address of print
{
    f();
}
```

but I wonna know if I can use void pointers

it is for implement something like this

```
void print()
{
    cout << "hello!" << endl;
}

void increase(int& a)
{
    a++;
}

void execute(void *f) //receives the address of print
{
    void (*john)(); // declares pointer to function
    john = f; // assigns address of print to pointer
    john(); // execute pointer
}

int main()
{
    int a = 15;
    execute(increase(a));
    execute(&print); // function that sends the address of print
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working?

Comment: `void execute(void* f())` is syntactically not correct.

Comment: I know, im asking for corrections

Answer (score 5):

Using `gcc test.cpp` I get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void execute(void* (*)())’:
test.cpp:12:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)()’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void* (*)()’ [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:9:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void execute(void* (*)())’ [-fpermissive]
```

The signature for the `f` argument is incorrect. You need to use

```
void execute(void (* f)())
```

instead. Therefore, you don't need the cast when assigning to `john`:

```
john = f
```

Also, you can simplify this by calling `f` directly:

```
f(); // execute function pointer
```

**EDIT:** Since you want to use void pointers, you need to pass `f` as a void pointer:

```
void execute(void *f)
```

Here, you will need the assignment to `john`, but as `f` is already a `void *` you don't need the cast.

**NOTE:** Given that you are passing a void pointer, the `execute` function will accept anything and you will have runtime errors if you pass the wrong thing. For example:

```
void print_name(const char *name)
{
    printf("%s", name);
}

void execute1(void *f);
void execute2(void (*f)());

int main()
{
    int value = 2;
    execute1(&value); // runtime crash
    execute1(&print_name); // runtime crash
    execute2(&value); // compile-time error
    execute2(&print_name); // compile-time error
}
```

Using a specifically defined function pointer lets the compiler generate an error at the point where you have passed the wrong argument type. This is preferred to crashing at runtime, as the runtime crash may be exploited as a security vulnerability and requires extensive testing to ensure this error does not occur.

Comment: so it's not possible then? I mean, passing a void pointer with functions? thanks though

Comment: What do you mean by passing a "void pointer with functions"? Do you mean passing a function that returns a pointer to another function (which you can do)?

Comment: sorry, i ment "passing a function as argument to another function with the use of void pointers in order to later specify the function structure"

Comment: You can't assign an address to a function to a void pointer. It may work on specific platforms, but it's illegal C and C++. If you want a function pointer, use a function pointer. If you don't want to specify the function signature, use a template.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`void execute(void (*f)()) //receives the address of print`

Or better use:

`void execute(boost::function<void()> const & f) //receives the address of print`

To accept functors as well, or replace `boost::` with `std::` if you are using compiler which supports C++11

Comment: Why use std::function instead of a normal pointer? Maybe some (old) API requires c-style functions, it is not safe to replace all occurences and without a good Delegate implementation I think you shouldn't